# Amazon CloudWatch API Not Returning

Tags: java, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following code (stripped down) snippet where the API call fails to return.

```
AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient awsClient
    = new AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient(accesskey, secretkey);
...
logger.info("Before putMetricDataAsync");
awsClient.putMetricDataAsync(req, asynchndl);
logger.info("After putMetricDataAsync"); // not showing
...
```

I'm skeptical maybe it was due to some firewall issue on the server sitting offshore.  Does anyone have a clue where the API connects to (i.e. host + port)?  Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Aws sdk are usually open source so you can have a look and see for yourself - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.java